# webpack CommonsChunkPlugin not work as expect

Tags: webpack, angular, ionic2

I'm using ionic2 + angular2. I want to to put my own code in one file and merge all the libraries in to another file.

The problem is the my own app still contains the libraries.

[image](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/842fe6bb90cf0d0303e0211a46762613dd4195d7/687474703a2f2f7777772e347368617265642e636f6d2f646f776e6c6f61642f5959706a304b525a62612f556e7469746c65642e706e673f736273723d6238666634313233393763623731326339376562323666343536643833663733393630266c6766703d33303030)

This is my config file:

```
var path = require('path'); var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {   root: path.resolve('/'),   
devtool: 'source-map', 
entry: {

    vendor:[path.normalize('es6-shim/es6-shim.min'),
      'reflect-metadata',
      'web-animations.min',
      'zone.js/dist/zone-microtask',
      'ionic-framework/ionic'
    ],
    app: path.resolve('www/app/app.ts')  
   },   
output: { 
    filename: '[name].js',   
 },  
 plugin:[
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: 
                               'vendor.js', minChunks: Infinity }),  
 ],  
 module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript',
        query: {
          'doTypeCheck': false
        },
        include: path.resolve('www/app'),
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve('node_modules/angular2'),
        loader: 'strip-sourcemap'
      },
      { test: /\.html$/,  loader: 'raw-loader' },
    ],
    noParse: [
      /es6-shim/,
      /reflect-metadata/,
      /web-animations/,
      /zone\.js(\/|\\)dist(\/|\\)zone-microtask/
    ]   },    resolve: {
    alias: {
      'web-animations.min': path.normalize('ionic-framework/js/web-animations.min')
    },
    extensions: ["", ".ts", ".js" ]   } };
```

Comment: i solved it , i was use plugin singular instead of plugins

Answer (score 0):

I think you've forgotten to specify `angular2` and `ionic2` modules for `vendor` entry:

```js
entry: {
    vendor:[
      path.normalize('es6-shim/es6-shim.min'),
      'reflect-metadata',
      'web-animations.min',
      'zone.js/dist/zone-microtask',
      'ionic-framework/ionic',

      // HERE: add all "angular2" and "ionic2" modules you're using
      'angular2/platform/browser',
      'angular2/core',
      'angular2/router',
      // and so on...
    ],

    // ...
}
```

Comment: many thanks @alexpods ,

 i already have tried  to insert angular2 , but didn't work , 

i saw angular2 libraries in the two files (vendor and app) without insert angular2 , coz  ionic2 will call angular2 during webpack building

Comment: i solved it , i was use plugin singular instead of plugins , thanks @alexpods